# I need a hidden field in an .NET Repeater control.

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-1.1

The catch is this is a .NET 1.0 project and there is no hidden field control...

So this is out of the question:

```
<asp HiddenField Runat="server" ID="hdn" />
```

I vaguely remember some type of HtmlHiddenInput class that allowed similar functionality...does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a regular input or create a custom server control.

```
<input type="hidden" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<input type="hidden" Name="HiddenControl" runat="server" />`
and at code behind page use below code:

`protected System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputHidden HiddenControl;`

You can assign value to hidden control:
`HiddenControl.value="Your value";`

Answer (score 0):

just use an asp textbox and the visible=false property

Comment: Its overkill to instantiate a textbox when you can just add 'runat=''server'' to a regular hidden input field.